# jQuery mouseover issue on Chrome/Opera/IE

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mouseover

I am using a simplified example of my problem.

I have icon 1 and icon 2. There is a 5px margin between them.

After hovering(using mouseover()) over icon 1, icon 1 expands and increases its size. This pushes icon 2 to the right.

Once I move the cursor to the right and out of icon 1, basically landing in the margin area between icon 1 and icon 2, icon 1 gets back to its original size and icon 2 goes back to its starting position. This starting position is underneath the cursor of the mouse. So at first there is nothing underneath the cursor but then icon 2 eventually ends up underneath it. Mozilla triggers a mouseover event for icon 2 but Chrome/Opera and IE will not.

Does anybody have an idea how I can get the mouseover trigger on all browsers?